# How can i disable padding on div while ion-content has padding on Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

I have the following code. My page has padding but i want to remove padding on div container.

I try `no-padding` or `no-padding!important` but it does not work.

How can i solve that problem? Thanks.

```
<ion-content padding no-bounce>

  <div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="box">
      <ion-grid text-center>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-33>
            ...
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-33>
            ...
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-33>
            ...
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Never header of or seen `no-padding` before, I know it's not valid CSS rule, so try `padding: 0px;` instead - might also help applying `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements which have padding, **e.g:** `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` **MDN** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: and if you somply remove `padding` without adding anything .. or try padding="false"

Comment: @TemaniAfif i want to solve that without removing padding.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError no-padding isn't a CSS rule, here we are using Ionic, and this will behave as a CSS class

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes, no-padding is valid for ionic. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: Good to know - thanks guys!

Comment: you can try adding negative margin to boxContainer then.

Comment: You can use Attribute ````<div no-padding></div>```` Please follow below link for details list of related attributes https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#element-padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif negative margin changes div position, does not work.

Comment: @Anjum.... I try that before but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I can not solve that like i want but found this way.

I remove padding from ion-padding. And added the other divs except the box one. For example.

```
<ion-content  no-bounce>

  <div class="boxContainer" padding-top="">
    <div class="box">
      <ion-grid text-center>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-33>
            <p class="walletTextParag">Cüzdanınız:</p>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-33>
            <h1 class="walletText">{{ (profileData | async)?.wallet}} ₺</h1>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-50>
            <button class="walletButton" ion-button="" icon-left color="color1" (click)="seePaymentsArchive()">
              <ion-icon name="ios-calendar"></ion-icon>
              Ödeme geçmişi
            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

You can add padding the other divs easily like

```
<div padding>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the css that is applied by ionic on the elements that you want to have no padding. For instance if the class added by ionic is `box` then add a custom class say `no-padding` and override the padding defined in a more specific CSS rule in your custom css file.

Something like:

```
div.box.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

You might not even need to add `!important` tag if ionic doesn't use `!important` in the `box` class

Comment: can you share a fiddle ? would like to see what does your code look like

Comment: i do not know how to create an ionic fiddle :( but if you know ionic i can send github link maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding-left ion-padding-right ion-padding-bottom">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Attribute such as `<div no-padding > </div>` 
or you can try below code

```
ion-content .boxContainer.box 
  {
   padding: 0
  }
```

Please follow below link for more supported ionic attributes [Ionic website link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#element-padding)